# Visual Studio linker cannot find libboost_system

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, linker, boost-asio

I'm using VS 2008 and want to use the boost::asio library.
I could get this to work in a new project (I want to include boost/bind.hpp and boost/asio.hpp), but in an existing project I get this error:

fatal error LNK1104: Datei "libboost_system-vc90-mt-sgd-1_46.lib" cannot be found.

I can't find this file in the boost directory, but this one: libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_46.lib (gd instead of sgd) What could that mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've used the Boost installer from BoostPro. If so reinstall it and make sure you select `Multithread Debug, static runtime`.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost names its libraries based on what options were used in compiling them](http://interreality.org/bzroot/boost/more/separate_compilation.html#auto-link).  "mt," for instance, means "multi-threaded runtime"; and I'm sure you can figure out what "vc90" means (compared to, say, "gcc4").  I think the "s" means "static."

Your solution is to first make sure you're using the same options that were used in building the library, and then change the name of the file you're linking against in the project options.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have to go to the project properties and change the name of the boost library that is currently included for linking. If you have libboost_system-vc90-mt-**gd**-1_46.lib, you should use it.

```
Configuration Properties => Linker => Input => Additional dependencies
```

Comment: For certain compilers (and VC++2008 is one of them) Boost.Asio does autolinking (`#pragma link`) so there's no additional library to add.

Comment: @eugen +1 for being correct, -1 for confusing with #pragma comment lib :) - #pragma link is not supported on VS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Hertzel: thank you for the clarification & the link, I got them mixed-up indeed.